# VBA: Trim entire column to Left and Right. Add hour to each value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where from K3-K? I have a value of 06:00:00-20:00:00. I would like to paste, in N3, the entire column, but just to have 07:00:00 (first 8 characters and adding an hour). I'd also like in column O3 the entire column for the end time (21:00:00) which also includes adding an hour.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What to you mean by "(first 8 characters and adding an hour)"? What did you try yet? Can you show us your VBA code?

Comment: I haven't any VBA code yet. I've been doing it in cell thus far;

=LEFT($K3,8)+TIME(1,0,0)

I don't know where to begin in VBA (still a beginner). But going forward, I need the value generated to not have the formula in cell.

Comment: I've just managed to work out half of it; the Left trim;

Dim TmRange As Range
Dim StartTm As Range

Set TmRange = Worksheets("IMPORT_ORDERS").Range(Range("K3"), Range("K3").End(xlDown))
Set StartTm = Worksheets("IMPORT_ORDERS").Range("N3")

For i = 1 To TmRange.Count

    StartTm(i, 1).Value = Left(TmRange(i, 1).Value, 8)

Next i

Comment: Can you add a picture of your excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're more than halfway there. Would the below finish it off?

```
Sub TimeAdd()

    Dim TmRange As Range
    Dim StartTm As Range
    Dim EndTm As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set TmRange = Worksheets("IMPORT_ORDERS").Range(Range("K3"), Range("K3").End(xlDown))
    Set StartTm = Worksheets("IMPORT_ORDERS").Range("N3")
    Set EndTm = Worksheets("IMPORT_ORDERS").Range("O3")

    For i = 1 To TmRange.Count
       StartTm.Offset(i - 1).Value = Left(TmRange(i, 1).Value, 8) + TimeValue("1:00:00")
       EndTm.Offset(i - 1).Value = Right(TmRange(i, 1).Value, 8) + TimeValue("1:00:00")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I found a slightly different alternative using your code above.